# convert yaml to json in bash using perl

Tags: json, bash, perl, yaml, data-conversion

I am trying to convert a yaml-string to json in bash using perl (unfortunately it has to be like this) and am having problems.
It works when I write it to a temporary file and convert that but unfortunately I do not have enough perl-experience to change it to work with a bash-variable to perform identically.
I need to do that because I want to convert many files quite often and always creating temporary files is slow/inefficient and in my case also a security issue.

This is the command that is working with the temporary file:

```
jsonfile=$(perl -MYAML::XS=LoadFile -MJSON::XS=encode_json -e 'for (@ARGV) { for (LoadFile($_)) { print encode_json($_),"\n" } }' ${tempfile} )
```

can I somehow change this to something along this?

```
jsonfile=$(echo "${yaml_string}" | perl .....)
```

I slightly changed the parameters and tried something like this but the output is quite different and not usable:

```
jsonfile=$(echo "${yaml_string}" | perl -MYAML::XS=Load -MJSON::XS=encode_json -e 'for (<>) { for (Load($_)) { print encode_json($_),"\n" } }')
```

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have JSON::XS and[YAML::XS installed, you can use the[`json_xs` command line utility that JSON::XS brings in its distribution. No need to roll your own: `json_xs -f yaml -t json <input.yml` to read STDIN from a file. All the solutions the other answers have given apply to this, it just cuts down on your Perl code.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `bash` as your shell, you can provide the contents of the yaml variable as a [herestring](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings) instead of piping the output of `echo`:

```
perl -MYAML::XS -MJSON::XS -0777 -E 'say encode_json(Load(<>))' <<<"${yaml_string}"
```

The `-0777` [switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/perlrun.html) is  a perl convention to tell `<>`/`readline` to read all of its input as a single value instead of as a line at a time.

Comment: Though if you can install `yq`, I'd go with the simpler `yq read - -jP <<<"${yaml_string}"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using arg:

```sh
# sh, bash
perl -MYAML::XS -MJSON::XS -e'CORE::say encode_json(Load($ARGV[0]))' -- "$yaml_string"
```

Using env var:

```
# sh, bash
yaml_string="$yaml_string" perl -MYAML::XS -MJSON::XS -e'CORE::say encode_json(Load($ENV{yaml_string}))'

# sh, bash
export yaml_string
perl -MYAML::XS -MJSON::XS -e'CORE::say encode_json(Load($ENV{yaml_string}))'
```

Using STDIN:

```sh
# sh, bash
printf '%s' "$yaml_string" | perl -MYAML::XS -MJSON::XS -0777e'CORE::say encode_json(Load(<>))'

# bash
perl -MYAML::XS -MJSON::XS -0777e'CORE::say encode_json(Load(<>))' <<<"$yaml_string"

# bash
perl -MYAML::XS -MJSON::XS -0777e'CORE::say encode_json(Load(<>))' <( printf '%s' "$yaml_string" )
```